# Service Fabric tutorial - can't connect once deployed to Azure cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have followed the tutorial here to deploy a .NET application to Azure Fabric Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-host-app-in-a-container

All appears fine right through to the last step when I try to connect to the web application running in Service Fabric in Azure when I receive a "The site can't be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error.

Also after a few minutes, when viewing the health state of the application in the Service Fabric blade in Azure I see it move to Error state (unfortunately it doesn't give more detail on the error and I am unable to authenticate against the Explorer, although I suspect that is a separate issue).

I followed the tutorial exactly, the only steps where it wasn't overly clear was when creating the cluster from within Visual Studio and choosing the VM image type - here I have tried with both "WindowsServerSemiAnual DataCentre-Core-1709-with-Containers" and "WindowsServer 2016-Datacenter-with-Containers".

Comment: I've now managed to connect to the Service Fabric Explorer (had to add the client cert to my cert store). The error was "Error event: SourceId='System.FM', Property='State'. Partition is below target replica or instance count.", but this has now transitioned with no intervention from me to a health state. I can now access the web site (albeit with some errors). I will answer this question with more details as it becomes clearer what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

It appears I simply hadn't given Service Fabric long enough to start the application - 30 mins or so later and all is running ok.

Confusing thing was that it starts by saying that the application state is healthy, it then transitioned to Error and then back to healthy.